# jQuery slider color picker / slider to change background

Tags: jquery, slider, color-picker

I'm trying to do:

Decreasing the temperature values of the slider, I need that circle that represents the star gradually increase and change background color as this link: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

But my code isn't doing it.....See lines from $("#s_tem").slider({
See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/19/

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the variable chosenColor values like: #597459745974

Which are not valid CSS color attributes.

[Edit] Here's some code that should get you going:

```
$("#s_tem").slider({
    change: function(event, ui)
    {       
        var hexValue = ui.value.toString(16).toUpperCase();
        if (hexValue.length < 2) hexValue = "0" + hexValue;

        var chosenColor = NumberToHexColor(hexValue);

        $('#t_tem').val(chosenColor);
        $("#star").css('background-color', chosenColor);

    },
    value: 5800,
    min: 2300,
    max: 40000,
    step: 100,  
});

function NumberToHexColor(Number)
{
    var HexColor = '' + Number;
    while (HexColor.length < 6) 
    {
        HexColor = '0' + HexColor;
    }

    return '#'+ HexColor;
}
```

Comment: But how do I fix this? 
I can not find how I am assigning these values.

Comment: I did what you showed me, is correct. But when manipulating the slide temperature it should increase or decrease with the star and change the color. If the circle to increase the color should go for an orange. Like here:http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

Comment: Instead of change, use the slide event.  I would put the code to do the two tasks in two separate function to keep things cleaner.  Call both functions in the slide event.

Comment: See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/27/ 

But not doing the way it does here: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

When I change the slider to the left and the star should grow and change color when I change the slider to the right the star should decrease and change color.

Comment: Instead of:  change: function(event, ui), use slide: function(event, ui)

Comment: I did it. But i realized that by manipulating the slider temperature is changing the values of the luminosity slider and not the values ​of temperature.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/28/

Comment: I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/tmDpZ/4/

But the star does not increase nor decrease as here: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html